# How can I save lots of image into png format in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, image-editing, bulk

I have about thousands images, I want to open it in preview, and click "save as", use the same name, and save as png. All these images just do the similar thing, instead of click one by one, how can I do so?

Comment: It's simple. Here's a tutorial I found on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yj3f9VLbqhI

Comment: Please clarify -- are you just renaming? Or are these images in a different format and you're also converting to `png` format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable with working on the Terminal, you could perhaps look at the man page for the `sips` command. In particular, with that command, you could use the `-s format png` switch to convert image files to the PNG format.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an Automator workflow to get the contents of a folder (copy if you want to keep the originals) and then convert to a desired file format.